# Conexão com banco de dados ASP.NET CORE 2

Tags: asp.net, conexão, microsoft-azure, asp.net-core

Estou iniciando com asp.net, mas especificamente com asp.net core 2.

Estou lendo a documentação contida no docs.microsoft.com.

Porém, tenho uma dúvida. Como faço conexão a um DB?

No PHP utilizo PDO, porém no asp.net core 2 utilizo o que?

Comment: Você vai sentir uma diferença bem grande. Como você esta na tecnologia mais recente te indico conhecer o Nuget (controlador de pacotes) e o Entity Framework (ORM) 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/

Comment: Então, estou estudando o Entity Framework Core, porém eu realmente ainda não entendi a conexão em sí. O uso dele sim. Até aonde entendi ele é usado para modelagem dos dados. Obrigado pelos links! Vou olhar.

Comment: No Code First as tabelas são geradas a partir das entidades (o banco já deve existir), mas você pode gerar as entidades a paritr de um banco já existente. Lembrando que o Entity Framework é nativo do SQL Server pro demais bancos tem que baixar a versão especifica. A conexão fica dentro do webconfig e o nome da conexão é passada como paramentro no DBContext. Ve esse meu repositorio ve se te da uma luz, dentro da pasta model
https://github.com/krismorte/LigueMe

Comment: Entendi, por exemplo se eu for conectar no SQL dB da Azure eu teria que conectar lá. Mas se a tabela já existe no banco de dados, o dbset vai rodar novamente?

Comment: Sim, também da certo.

Comment: Krismorte, uma outra dúvida surgiu. O que é o ado.net? Pelo que eu vi ele é uma tecnologia .Net para conexão com o dB. Ele substitui o entity? Cara, desculpa as dúvidas mas esse mundo .Net é bem grande em vista do Photoshop e com várias tecnologias embarcadas.

Comment: ADO.NET é um conjundo de classes predefinidas dentro da plataforma va~çao de banco de dados a objetos visuais. Conexão ado.net normalmente é fetia através apenas do web.config, nos seus objetos faz referência apenas ao nome da conexão.

Comment: Estou começando a entender. Hoje eu li mais uma parte da documentação do entity. Percebi que o dbcontext faz a conexão em si e ele usa ado.net nas entranhas. Para conectar em um dB Azure eu pego a string ado net, coloco no appsettings e faço o dbcontext pelo entity. Ainda não descobri como salvar os dados, não cheguei nisso.

Answer (score 1):

1. Instale uma versão do SQL server communtity para você poder fazer alguns testes.
2. crei um novo projeto em asp.net core incluindo autenticação individual. Por padrão o Asp vai criar a string de conexão no arquivo appsetting.json parecido com a linha abaixo:

`"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-WebApplication3-AE3FA43F-A3AF-4A87-8999-727298B6B01F;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },`

3. Crie os seus modelos de classes na pasta Model do tipo: cliente, empresa e seus dados por exemplo

   public class cliente
      {

   ```
     [Key]
     public string nome { get; set; }
     public string cpf { get; set; }
   ```

   }
4. Adicione um controller usando a opção Controlador MVC com exibições, usando o Entity FrameWork
5. escolha o modelo de classe que quer criar as views, controllers
6. esolha o modelo de dados, provavelmente você vai encontrar "ApplicationDbContext" como padrão

é nessa classe "ApplicationDbContext" que você vai encontrar o que procura. As configurações de conexão, poderá configurar algumas propriedades das tabelas, primary key e etc..

No startup.cs você poderá configurar o tipo de banco para MySQL ou useSqlServer, eu uso o MySql. O padrão é o sqlServer e vc vai encontrar nesse arquivo

```
 services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Lembra do arquivo appsetting.json? é aí que é chamada a string de conexão com o bando de dados "DefaultConnection".
espero ter ajudado.